# Find a constant $C_p$ that satisfies $|f(x+p)-f(y+p)|\le C_p|f(x)-f(y)|$

Tags: uniform-continuity, constants

Let $B^n$ be the unit open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $p\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to B^n$ defined as $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+|x|}x$.

I believe there are constants $C_p>0$ such that $|f(x+p)-f(y+p)|\le C_p|f(x)-f(y)|$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$. I tried things such as $C_p=1+|p|$ or $C_p=(1+|p|)^2$ (these seem good candidates) but I'm having problems with some estimates. Any other constant works, of course.

Edit: Some advance in the problem:

Note first that $f$ is actually an homeomorphism from $R^n$ to $B^n$ so in particular it's injective.
So we are to find a constant $C_p$ such that $|f(x+p)-f(y+p)|\le C_p|f(x)-f(y)|$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$. We may assume that $x\neq y$ and so the last inequality becomes
\begin{equation}
  \frac{(1+|x|)(1+|y|)}{(1+|x+p|)(1+|y+p|)}\frac{|(1+|y+p|)(x+p)-(1+|x+p|)(y+p)|}{|(1+|y|)x-(1+|x|)y|}\le C_p
\end{equation}

But note that $(1+|x|)/(1+|x+p|)\le 1+|p|$ and similar for $y$ so we have only to find a constant $Q_p$ such that
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{|(1+|y+p|)(x+p)-(1+|x+p|)(y+p)|}{|(1+|y|)x-(1+|x|)y|}\le Q_p
\end{equation*}

Edit 2: More advances in the problem

Let's assume that $p\neq 0$. I think that $Q_p=1+2|p|$ and, in fact, that $1+2|p|$ can't be improved. A straightforward calculation shows that 
\begin{align*}
  (1+|y+p|)(x+p)-(1+|x+p|)(y+p)=&|y+p|(x+p)-|x+p|(y+p)+|x|y-|y|x\\
                                &+(1+|y|)x-(1+|x|)y
\end{align*}
so that 
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{|(1+|y+p|)(x+p)-(1+|x+p|)(y+p)|}{|(1+|y|)x-(1+|x|)y|}\le\frac{||y+p|(x+p)-|x+p|(y+p)+|x|y-|y|x|}{|(1+|y|)x-(1+|x|)y||}+1
\end{equation*}
I claim that
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{||y+p|(x+p)-|x+p|(y+p)+|x|y-|y|x|}{|(1+|y|)x-(1+|x|)y|}<2|p|
\end{equation*}
and that this bound can't be improved because taking $y=0$ and $x=-\lambda p$ and letting $\lambda\to \infty$ we see that the left hand side of the above equation tends to $2|p|$.

However I can't prove the last inequality. Some numerical tests with Mathematica tell me that it's true though.

Comment: I did not try, but I guess that you may reduce to a 1D analysis on any straight line thru the origin. Indeed, it seems to me that $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are  as far as they can if $x$ and $y$ lie on the same line.

Comment: I also noticed something similar but I cannot arrive to something concrete.