# strict inequality with norms $\frac{||y+p|(x+p)-|x+p|(y+p)+|x|y-|y|x|}{|(1+|y|)x-(1+|x|)y|}<2|p|$

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces

We work in $R^n$ and $|x|=\sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_n^2}$. Let $p\in R^n$ different from $0$ and $x,y\in R^n$ with $x\neq y$ then
\begin{equation*}
  f(x,y,p)=\frac{||y+p|(x+p)-|x+p|(y+p)+|x|y-|y|x|}{|(1+|y|)x-(1+|x|)y|}<2|p|
\end{equation*}

I think the equality can't be achieved but letting $y=0$ and $x=-\lambda p$ and letting $\lambda\to\infty$ we see that $2|p|$ can't be improved because the left side of the inequality tends to $2|p|$ from the left.

I've done some tests that tell me it's true but I'm not completely sure, It looks weird.

If $x\neq 0$ then it seems that  $f(x,y,p)\le f(x,0,p)$ but then again I can't prove it.

Comment: Seems related to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1431631/find-a-constant-c-p-that-satisfies-fxp-fyp-le-c-pfx-fy)

Comment: Looks like it's conclustion

Comment: It looks? It is exactly the same notation and observations. When positing a question based on another question it is customary to link to that post.